# htaccess rewriterule

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a WordPress theme with the following .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Which removes the "index.php" from the url. But I would like to remove some stuff from my start url, which looks something like "page.com/dir/dir2/page.html", to "page.com". So I tried adding

```
RewriteRule . /dir/dir2/page.html [L]
```

after the first rule, but it doesn't seem to work. What do I need to do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

`RewriteRule ^dir/dir2/page\.html$ - [L]`

This should work to.

Edit: little big mistake I did there. NOW it should work

Comment: Hmm, dunno if im doing something wrong, but when i add it under "RewriteEngine On", the url still looks the same.

Comment: I still dont get it to work. All i need to do it to add it after the RewriteBase line, right?

Comment: Put it after the last RewriteRule (RewriteRule . /index.php [L])

Comment: Thanks, but it doesnt work, no idea why. The index.php thing is working as it should